# Launchd runs with manual "launchctl start", but not on StartCalendarInterval

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, launchd, launch-daemon

I have a very simple Launch Daemon, com.daily.vocab.plist, which simply runs a basic script. It is supposed to run every day at a certain time (using StartCalendarInterval), but I can't get that to happen. Many posts online are saying it runs a minute or two off, but for me it just never runs.

I have been setting the run time to be 5 minutes in the future while I am testing, and now have it set to run at the 0th second of every minute, just so I can get it to work. Once it's working, I will set it to my desired daily run time.

As advised in [this tutorial](http://launchd.info/), it is saved in /Library/LaunchDaemons. I loaded it manually with `launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.daily.vocab.plist`. I do in fact see it has loaded when I run `launchctl list`. When I manually tell it to run with `launchctl start com.daily.vocab`, it works immediately as expected. The only issue is that the StartCalendarInterval seems to be ignored. I am on Mavericks on my Macbook.

Here is the file: com.daily.vocab.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
      <string>com.daily.vocab</string>
    <key>Program</key>
      <string>/Users/MGS/developer/projects/vocab-sms/scripts/DEvocab.sh</string>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
      <dict>
        <key>Second</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
      </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Ideally, I believe I want it to run at 7:15am every day making the `StartCalendarInterval` section be instead:

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
      <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>7</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>15</integer>
    </dict>
```

If you could even share an example of a LaunchDaemon you got to work using StartCalendarInterval and every step you made to make it work (e.g. running `launchctl load x.x.x.plist`), that would be really helpful!

**Solution**: This local daemon should actually be a user agent, so it needed to be saved in and loaded from the ~/Library/LaunchAgents directory. From there, I also needed to unload the agent and reload the agent.

NOTE: Daemons/Agents do not automatically update in launchd until you unload/load. You can't just save the updated .plist and expect it to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

launchd plists saved in `/Library/...` are daemons / agents in the **local** domain and have to be loaded with `sudo`. Without `sudo` you're loading the daemon in the **user** domain which doesn't match the actual path.

Since you are calling a script in the **user** domain anyway, save the script in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` (it's not a daemon). The plist syntax is supposed to be correct.

Comment: Hmm. Still not working. The file com.daily.vocab.plist is now saved in ~/Library/LaunchAgents and I have loaded it (without sudo) into launchd. launchctl list confirms this. But it still is not running. Any special permissions I need to add? Does the shell script the agent calls need to have special permissions?

Comment: I just changed the agent to use StartInterval instead of StartCalendarInterval and that worked exactly as expected. Any ideas on why StartCalendarInterval isn't working?

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with the `StartCalendarInterval` syntax and further permissions are not needed either. But of course by setting minute and hour you have to wait 24 hours for the next occurrence ;-)

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I hadn't unloaded and reloaded the agent since switching from the original /Library/LaunchDaemons directory. Once I moved it to ~/Library/LaunchAgents, and unloaded and reloaded the .plist, it worked.
Thanks so much @Vadian!

Comment: I recommend checking out the util "Launch Control" for creating and managing launchd jobs.  The confusion around the right directory and whether a job is loaded or not becomes immediately clear with Launch Control.  Cheers!  (not mine, I just love it)

Answer (score 0):

will have to change the permission for the bash file

```
chmod u+v /Users/MGS/developer/projects/vocab-sms/scripts/DEvocab.sh
```